# Memory Error when exporting multiple PDFs

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a macro which generates hundreds of PDFs by exporting a range of cells from a sheet in my workbook. The way the program works is that the program changes a couple values on the sheet, formulas then fill in cells, and then the sheet is exported as a PDF. After the program generates about 150 pdfs, Excel crashes and displays

> memory errors like "not enough resources to complete action"

If I comment out the line of code that exports the pdf, I can run the program over and over again with no issues. If I change the exported file type to an excel workbook, I can also run the program with no issues. Here is the print function I use to export pdfs.

```
Function Prnt(print_area As Range)

Dim myDir As String, mySht As String
Dim supplier As String
DoEvents
supplier = Range("F4").Value
myDir = Range("y2").Value
mySht = Range("y1").Value
mySht = RemoveSpecialChars(mySht)
On Error Resume Next
MkDir myDir
On Error Resume Next
myDir = myDir + "\" + Range("z1").Value
On Error Resume Next
MkDir myDir
On Error Resume Next
supplier = RemoveSpecialChars(supplier)
myDir = myDir & "\" & supplier
On Error Resume Next
MkDir myDir

print_area.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=myDir & "\" & mySht, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set print_area = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Function
```

The line that I comment out or change to prevent the error is the line that starts with "print_area.Exportas...". My print area consists of a couple linked images and cells with formulas in them. I noticed that removing the linked images caused the program to crash after about 250 pdfs were generated which was a slight improvement. I can't imagine why the error is occurring and any help would be appreciated.  I really need the files to be in pdf format and am open to any suggestions or alternative ways to achieve this.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is not line specific.  It will turn of the error catching till you put `On Error Goto 0`.  You only need one and then the second after the lines you want to skip on the error check.  Also it would be better to do your own checks with `If` statements and skip the whole `On Error ...` so you do not inadvertently cover an error that would help figure out the problem.

Comment: I wrote a short routine to call your code and produced 1000 PDFs with no errors.  Two changes I made were I changed the function to a sub, since you're not returning a value anyway, and I skipped all the sub folder creation part because I didn't want to be bothered creating all that false data.  The code itself works.  I would guess that the problem is in how it's called.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I removed the On Errors and replaced them with Ifs.  Hopefully when it breaks it will throw a useful error.  Thanks Hrothgar.  It is very strange because commenting out the export line fixes everything suggesting that the pdf creation is where the error occurs.

Comment: Might be better to consistently use `&` for string concatenation than `+`. I would use defensive `If` statements to avoid errors (instead of `On Error Resume Next`). Also, test if `mysht` as returned by `RemoveSpecialChars` is a valid filename before attempting to export. Might be an idea to stick a `DoEvents` (at least whilst testing) after exporting.

Comment: By Going through the program one line at a time when it gets close to the 150 PDF mark, I have found a clue for what is happening right before the program breaks.  My two linked images suddenly do not load and an X icon comes up with the text: "The picture can't be displayed.".  It seems the act of creating the pdfs somehow creates a memory leak that eventually crashes the program.  No idea why this is happening.

Comment: https://downloadmoreram.com/

Answer (score 0):

Removing all linked images from the print area prevents the program from breaking.  Seems like exporting images causes some memory leak.  I've generated 600 PDFs successfully without a breakdown yet but I am going to run the program over and over again to see if something else might be contributing to the leak as well.

By deleting and recreating every image in the print area on every iteration, pausing my program every 50 iterations, and throwing in a DoEvents after the pause, the problem has now been fixed.  No clear answer as to why the error occurred in the first place.

Comment: rather than a memory leak, could it be that each export creates handles for the graphic objects that aren't released ? Use Task Manager to see the Handles count as your code runs with the graphics in the export. You may be able to manually call a garbage collector to release the resources.

Comment: Good idea.  Can't seem to notice any increase in handles while the program executes but I added a part of my macro to delete and recreate the images on every iteration.  Maybe that will delete any handles on the images.